# groupBy element in a List of String in Scala

Tags: scala

I would like to use the right way to do it in a pure FP style.

how to do that in Scala?

```
case class Notes(title: String, body: String, tags: List[String])

val notesList: List[Notes] = retrieveNotesList() // it works
```

Multiple notes can have same tags.

Now I would like to group notes by tag. I'm not able to complete the code to group notes by tag:

```
val notesGroupedByTag: Map[String, List[Notes]] = notesList.groupBy {
   case note: Notes => note.tags
}.[_to be completed_]
```

Comment: You've written that you want the result to be of type `Map[String, List[String]]`. What should the key be and what should the value be? I'm guessing key is a tag? What about the values?

Comment: I agree with @JoeK. Maybe you meant `Map[String, List[Notes]]`?

Comment: I fixed it to match what I'm looking for. the key is "tag" and the value is a list of notes.  Something like `Map ("scala" -> List(Note_1, Note_2), "code" -> List(Note_1, Note_3), "theory" -> List(Note_2, Note_3))` that is what I'm looking for. THANKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
notesList.flatMap(n => n.tags.map(t => (t, n))) // List[(tag, note)]
         .groupBy(_._1)                         // Map[tag, List[(tag, note)]
         .mapValues(_.map(_._2))                // Map[tag, List[note]]
```

Comment: in this way the key is just a single "char" and not the entire tag name.

Comment: it works as well and it follows your comment on the other posted. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

One way is to go thought an intermediate `List[Tag, Notes]`:

```
// Things are a bit more clear with type aliases...
type Title = String
type Tag   = String

case class Notes(title: Title, body: String, tags: List[Tag])

val notes: List[Notes] = retrieveNotesList()

val tagedTitle: List[(Tag, Notes)] =
  notes.flatMap(n => n.tags.map(_ -> n))

val notesGroupedByTag: Map[Tag, List[Notes]] =
  tagedTitle.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2))
```